# What does multilevel scheme means?/

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The following passage from Thomas Numerical PDE:

[image]

What is the meaning of two level scheme? For example, lets take $v_t + v_x = 0$. The usual scheme I have studied so far for example is

$$ \frac{ u_{k+1}^n - u_k^n }{\Delta x} + \frac{ u_k^{n+1}- u_k^n }{\Delta t } = 0$$

where $u_k^n = v(k\Delta x, n \Delta t)$ . What does Thomas mean by two-level scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Thomas refers to "levels", what he means is actually time instants or steps. The scheme you write for the simple equation would, in his notation, be a two-level scheme. In particular, here he denotes by $\mathbf{u}^n$ the vector of all space values of the approximation at time $t_n$.

A multilevel scheme on $l+1$ levels (often in literature [multistep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method)) would be a scheme that involves the time snapshots of the solutions $\mathbf{u}^{n-1}, \mathbf{u}^{n-2},\ldots \mathbf{u}^{n-l}$ to compute the value $\mathbf{u}^n$.

In any case, this is explained quite thoroughly in the book you cite, two pages before your screenshot (beginning of section 2.2.4).

Comment: thanks for your reply!